# Jenkinsfile Kubernetes expose container ports

Tags: selenium, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to export a port on my Kubernetes container in my Jenkins pipeline.

I have looked online, and I just can't work out how to get this to work.

I need to export port 4444 to the selenium-hub container.

```
def label = "selenium-hub-${UUID.randomUUID().toString()}"

podTemplate(label: label, yaml: """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: selenium-hub
    image: selenium/hub:3.4.0
    
  - name: selenium-chrome
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.4.0
    env:
    - name: HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR
      value: localhost
    - name: HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT
      value: 4444
    - name: DISPLAY
      value: :99.0
    - name: SE_OPTS
      value: -port 5556
  - name: selenium-firefox
    image: selenium/node-firefox:3.4.0
    env:
    - name: HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR
      value: localhost
    - name: HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT
      value: 4444
    - name: DISPLAY
      value: :98.0
    - name: SE_OPTS
      value: -port 5557
```

I currently get the ip from the hub, and pass that onto my tests to run via the grid

```
  node(label) {
        containerLog('selenium-hub')
        sh('hostname -i')
        POD_IP = sh(script: "hostname -i", returnStdout: true).toString().replaceAll('\\n', '');
        node() {
            sh("POD_IP='${POD_IP}' UI_URL=https://EEEEEE.net/ SERVICE_URL=https://WWWWWW.net/ ./node_modules/webdriverio/bin/wdio ./tests/UI/helpers/configs/wdio.GRID.conf.js --nolazy")
        }
```

I would seem that at the point the tests run, it is unable to access the grid, so I believe it is due to port 4444 not being exposed, but I can't work out how to do it in Kubernetes.

I have tried some examples online, but don't seem to be getting any closer.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a Kubernetes pod as an abstraction of a traditional server. If a container in the pod is exposing a service like mysql or in this case selenium on a particular port then all the other containers in the pod can access that service on the selected port by default:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#resource-sharing-and-communication

Rather than using the POD_IP just try using localhost:4444 (or whatever port you are needing) to access the service.

I use the same pattern for accessing mysql in a sidecar container during unit tests in various builds.

Comment: So that works for the "node" containers hitting the "grid" but, as our kubernetes server is a slave to our jenkins server, the ip is different, so I can't use local host, the POD_IP get the ip of the slave that the containers is running on, I need to then expose 4444 so that it is open on the slave so that the master jenkins can access it....if that makes sense, thanks

Comment: @Karl why do you need the Jenkins master to be able to access the slave? In your example it looks like you are running the hub and the browser in the same pod. The communication is going from the browser to the hub right?

Answer (score 0):

Service allows your applications to receive traffic. So you need one of those to expose access to your selenium deployment:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: selenium-hub
  labels:
    app: selenium-hub
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 4444
    targetPort: 4444
    name: port0
  selector:
    app: selenium-hub
  type: NodePort
  sessionAffinity: None
```

For more details  https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/selenium